# EF Core Create database row if not exists

Tags: entity-framework, transactions, entity-framework-core, optimistic-concurrency, database-concurrency

So I'm hitting my webservice to save a row in the database if the id doesn't already exist.  So I do this in two steps.  First I run a select on the context to bring back the entity with the given id.  If that returns null, I create a new entity and call saveChanges.  This works perfectly almost always.  However, when there are multiple requests hitting the webserver at the same time, there is a chance that 2 requests could run at pretty much the same time.  When this happens, there is the chance that they both create a row.  This is actually happening.

How would you handle this situation?

p.s. I'm using EntityFramework Core.

Comment: Well, it's not an elegant solution, but I ended up creating a stored proc to handle it.